# map + foldl = mapfoldl

Tags: prolog

I was wondering... In the standard library of some Prolog systems, there are meta-predicates like `maplist` and `foldl`.

In general, when using meta-predicates (like the ones above) with [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) we **always** need the "foldl" variants. What about the following `mapfoldl/5` (`mapfoldl//3`)?

```
mapfoldl(P_4,Xs,Zs,S0,S) :-
   list_mapfoldl_(Xs,Zs,S0,S,P_4).

list_mapfoldl_([],[],S,S,_).
list_mapfoldl_([X|Xs],[Y|Ys],S0,S,P_4) :-
   call(P_4,X,Y,S0,S1),
   list_mapfoldl_(Xs,Ys,S1,S,P_4).
```

What's your take on this code? They isn't this (or something very similar) already in the stdlibs?

Comment: I don't see folding, only mapping ?..

Comment: @WillNess. `call(P_4,X,Y,S0,S1)` does both. At this particular level there is no "fold", only "map". "fold" comes into play by how `S0`, `S1`, ..., `S` are threaded through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Logtalk library, you have a `map_reduce/5` predicate:

```
:- public(map_reduce/5).
:- meta_predicate(map_reduce(2, 3, *, *, *)).
:- mode(map_reduce(+callable, +callable, +term, ?list, ?term), zero_or_more).
:- info(map/5, [
    comment is 'Map a list and apply a fold left (reduce) to the resulting list.',
    argnames is ['Map', 'Reduce', 'Accumulator', 'List', 'Result']
]).

map_reduce(Map, Reduce, Acc, List, Result) :-
    map_reduce_(List, Map, Reduce, Acc, Result).

:- meta_predicate(map_reduce_(*, 2, 3, *, *)).
map_reduce_([], _, _, Result, Result).
map_reduce_([Arg| Args], Map, Reduce, Acc, Result) :-
    call(Map, Arg, Arg2),
    call(Reduce, Acc, Arg2, Acc2),
    map_reduce_(Args, Map, Reduce, Acc2, Result).
```

A main difference to your code is that you assume a single closure combining both the map and reduce operations in the Logtalk version. You also return the map result in addition to the final fold result.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I see "fold left" and "reduce" as two quite distinct operations. "fold" as a chain,  "reduce" as a trees; "fold" as "sequential", "reduce" as parallel. Look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88446/higher-order-prolog-predicates-combine-3-and-reduce-3 and the performance differences I observed when calculating an integer product with **many** multiplicands. Something similar can be seen with "bottom-up merge sort", and presumably many other operations that lean more towards "balanced binary tree" than "linear single-linked list". What's your take on this?

Comment: W.r.t. performance, Logtalk includes a meta-compiler that eliminates the meta-call overhead when using `map_reduce/5` and other library meta-predicates.

Comment: In the experiment with "reduce" vs "fold", meta-predicate invocation costs are negligible. Taking the amount of actual work into account, big integer multiplication is most efficient when the multiplicands have similar sizes (at least with GMP). The situation is similar with bottom-up merge sort. Still I see that there are many other occasions when meta-compilation shines, particularly when portability comes into play. Thank you.

Comment: Penalties from twice as slow to one order of magnitude slower for a meta-call compared to a direct call, depending on the Prolog system, are typical. Even worse if you use lambda expressions with the meta-calls (Logtalk's meta-compiler also compile away lambdas, btw).

Comment: Please don't get me wrong: I'm very much in favor of meta-compilation! But the speedup depends on the concrete operation being done. It is greatest for cases where there is little work is done per step. In the case of the big-integer product, "reduce" enables using O(N log N) algorithms when "fold" is stuck with O(N^2) algorithms.

Comment: Particularly, the idea of compiling the lambdas away (in a portable way) is very appealing!

Comment: `foldl g z (map f xs) =~ foldl (g . f) z xs` so there's no need for the new function, the reducing function can always be augmented to accommodate the mapping.